# Calling a c++ file from Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I have a Python code and, after running all the stuff in it, I want it to simply run a c++ file I have in the same directory. I read about Cython and BoostPython, but I don't think it is what I need (I could be wrong, obviously). I don't want to call functions, simply run the c++ algorithm. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to share data between python and the c++ program?

Comment: when you say "c++ file" do you mean a source file or an executable?

Comment: no, @snek_case, I just want to run the c++ program.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818   the source file.

Comment: You will need to compile (translate) the Source C++ file into an executable before you can run it.  You can have Python run a compiler and specify your program (along with other command line parameters), then have Python run the executable program.  An alternative is to find or create an interpreter for C++.

Comment: @donut C++ is not an interpreted language. It's a *compiled* language. You cannot run a source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try open it as a subprocess in your script like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["g++", "hello_world.cpp"])
tmp=subprocess.call("./a.out")
print("printing result")
print(tmp)
```